# Is DataTable unsuitable for this type of threaded operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, datatable

I have a CSV file with header.  Each row represents work that must be done involving HTTP requests and processing data.

I need to make this multithreaded so that is works faster but I am not sure if DataTable is suitable for this.

My process will be:

1. Load CSV to DataTable
2. A scheduler function will queue Tasks, assigning each task a DataTable row number (I will limit number of concurrent tasks)
3. Each Task will read just their assigned DataTable row.  Do the work then update the DataTable row accordingly and complete.
4. At the end or operation or on receipt of cancellation token the DataTable will be serialized back to CSV file.

Only 1 task will ever access an individual row but multiple tasks will be accessing their assigned rows at the same time.

Is this likely to give me problems?

As no two tasks will be accessing the same DataTable row is it even necessary to lock the DataTable before each time a Task reads from or writes to their DataTable row?

Comment: why can't you go and read the csv async?  you can do one quick read to get the length of the csv , then just start multiple tasks that go off, read the csv - perform their task and they're done.  Why do you need a readonly datatable storing identical info as the csv?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  The DataTable is not read only.  Each task will be reading their assigned row of DataTable, do some stuff then update that row in the DataTable.  The DataTable then gets serialized back to CSV at end of process.

Comment: ok then , you hadn't fully explained that - I thought it just held the info about what the tasks do

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use the CSV as a database.  Why are you doing that instead of just using a database?

Comment: I am supplied input as a CSV file and must update this CSV file.  The updated CSV file is the end goal and the format I must produce.

Comment: II don't understand why it has to be the exact same csv file that gets modified after the tasks have executed.  How is anyone going to know if after each task the task write a row into a new csv with results .  I also don't understand why you're not using a database- I get the requirements ,but you can read from a database , store in database , write into csv .  This way you have records of everything that happened .  The way you have it set up you will have no idea of the tasks that happened ,

Comment: How is writing to a new csv any different? Why do I need to save to a database? It just seems an unnecessary step. Once csv it loaded to memory what good will it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation of the [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, which states:

> **Thread Safety**
>
> This type is **safe for multithreaded read** operations. You must **synchronize any write** operations.

So you need to lock when you do updates. Row reads and processing should be safe.

Note that it is not fully clear about whether reads are safe while a write operation is performed. If you want to rather be safe than sorry, you could use a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Given that you are limiting the number of concurrent tasks, a good strategy to avoid a lot of lock contention might be to provide each of them with a (sequential) partition of row numbers, and have them perform batched updates on a number of processed rows.

Comment: I disagree. There are internal index changes on rows, even during reading. DataTable is thread safe, but DataRow is not, which makes DataTable threadsafeness irrelevant.